# replace NA after a first observation occurred

Tags: r, na

I have data with rows "username" and then columns with each day from 2016-09-06 to 2017-09-30 where each day is a column.

I have values L, T and C for each user on the days the observation occurred. For the dates with no observation I have NA.

I want to replace NA's with L, but only AFTER a user has had a first observation. So:

NA NA NA NA L NA NA L T C 
would become
NA NA NA NA L L L L TC

I have a small subset from my data but do not know how to insert this into the question. If needed, please let me know how I can provide this as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `library(zoo); na.locf(vec, na.rm = FALSE)#[1] NA  NA  NA  NA  "L" "L" "L" "L" "T" "C"`

Answer (score 1):

`na.locf0(x)` will fill in the `NA` values with the last occurring value in `x` while leaving leading `NA` values in place so that its output is the same length as its input; thus, if a position in `na.locf(x)` is not `NA` but that same position is `NA` in `x` then `na.locf0` would have filled it in.  Those positions have the value TRUE in the logical expression shown in the code below so set the values of `x` at those positions to `"L"`.  We use `replace` to do that non-destructively (i.e. we output the desired vector without modifying `x` itself).

```
library(zoo)

x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "L", NA, NA, "L", "T", "C") # test data
replace(x, !is.na(na.locf0(x)) & is.na(x), "L")
## [1] NA  NA  NA  NA  "L" "L" "L" "L" "T" "C"
```

#### Note

If we knew that the NAs to be filled in all follow `L` (as in the sample data in the question) then

```
na.locf0(x)
```

would be sufficient; however, if the general case is as described in the question then the `replace` code above will be needed.

#### Variation

A variation of the above is to replace all `NA` values with `"L"` and then in that replace those positions that are `NA` in `na.locf0(x)` with `NA`.

```
replace(replace(x, is.na(x), "L"), is.na(na.locf0(x)), NA)
## [1] NA  NA  NA  NA  "L" "L" "L" "L" "T" "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just do

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(vec, na.rm = FALSE)
#[1] NA  NA  NA  NA  "L" "L" "L" "L" "T" "C"
```

#### data

```
vec <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 'L', NA, NA, 'L', 'T', 'C')
```

Comment: thanks! this works, but unfortunately only when the first observation in the vector is "L". This can also be "T" or "C", but then if I use this code it fills all NA's after the first observation with either "T" or "C". Is there a way to specify that NA's should be filled with "L"?